# What Proton version is being used automatically for each game?

Tags: steam, linux, wine, the-great-ace-attorney-chronicles

I'm running [the-great-ace-attorney-chronicles](/questions/tagged/the-great-ace-attorney-chronicles) and forcing it to use Proton-7 because whatever default Proton it's using somehow breaks the video display.

But how do I find what the default is, so eventually when that default becomes good / version 7+, I know to turn off my selection and let Steam pick Proton automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default can be changed under `Steam settings > Steam Play`.

You may need to enable Developer mode to show this. This can be found in `Steam settings > System`.

If you select either *Stable* or *Experimental*, it will automatically upgrade to include the fixes in Version 7 for this particular title.

- Note that: If you're running Steam itself under proton or WINE , the option will not be visible (as Steam believes it's running on a Windows machine).

Comment: I don't much know about Proton or anything but isn't OP already running on Proton 7? I thought OP was asking, what version of Proton is used by default (and the last paragraph of the question)? I'm weak at English but this question doesn't look like asking how to force run on Proton 7???

Comment: @Skye-AT There is both a *per-game* and a *global* setting for what version to pick. Steam installs many proton versions due to regressions. Asker knows about the per-game setting, and wants to know where to find what the value of the global setting is.

Comment: Okay, so it seems to access Steam Client Devmode, I append a "-devmode" to the shortcut? But inside the client, running as Admin, I'm still not seeing "Steam Play" in the settings tabs? Still just got the regular Account, Family, ..., Shader Pre-Caching?

Comment: Running with "-dev" instead of "-devmode" gets me a Console tab after my username, at the top, at least? Store, Library, Community, NAME, Console.

Comment: Oh, okay, so Steam Play is only visible in Linux versions of the Steam Client? Perhaps add that in your answer? I thought I could change it on Windows, but no?

Comment: @Malady I could not have guessed that particular user error. If you're running steam,exe on WINE it's pretty likely you will have issues with (newer) games; the Ubuntu/Mint/etc. type distro version of WINE tends to be outdated by a couple years.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @aphid - Eh? No, I have a windows machine and a linux machine. Didn't feel like turning on my Linux machine just to try out your answer. Didn't think that'd matter.